G4A Sentry Error TypeError Nc(gtag/js) Failed to fetch
Anyone else experiencing errors like TypeError Nc(gtag/js) Failed to fetch on Sentry when sending requests to GA4?
I've tried manually replicating the issue but couldn't reproduce the error. Any insights or solutions would be appreciated!

We've been encountering an issue on Sentry with gtag/js resulting in Failed to fetch errors since June 3rd. It appears that most users experiencing this problem are using Chrome/Edge 125 or Chrome/Edge 126. We're currently investigating but have been unable to reproduce the issue so far. Just letting you know you're not alone.
How do you integrate the Google Tag Manager script ?

Yes - it's been ongoing for the last 10 days or so. Sentry keeps flagging line 218 in /gtag/js:
218: {snip} gTopics&&(d.browsingTopics=c.browsingTopics));try{return G.fetch(a,d),!0}catch(e){}}if(c&&c.noFallback)return!1;if(b)return Lc(a,b);Kc(a);re {snip}

@wlarcheveque We are also experiencing numerous Failed to fetch errors with gtag/js, predominantly affecting Chrome users. Please let me know if you've found a solution for this. Thanks a lot!

I can reproduce this by blocking access to www.google-analytics.com from DNS. But for some reason, the error only shows up on mobile, not on the desktop.

Update: June 21, 2024, we have not made any changes, and the error has disappeared from Sentry.

We encountered the same issue in early June, which was also a collect request initiated by gtag js, resulting in a Failed to Fetch error. It's worth noting that this error message appears in Chrome, while the error message in Firefox is NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. Safari shows Load failed. Based on these tips, it doesn't seem to be browser-related but rather likely due to some updates in GA. However, I have not found any relevant update notes so far.
I tried asking in the GA community but have not received any response yet. https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/280419259/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-error-suddenly-appears
For certain reasons, we are currently using both gtm js and gtag js simultaneously. There were no issues before June, so I'm not sure if this is the cause. If anyone else is also loading both scripts simultaneously, please let me know.

The issues are still present on our Sentry as of June 23, 2024. Did you contact anyone from Sentry?

@JeighFrost We haven't done any processing, neither with Sentry nor GA. However, it's worth mentioning that there are still a few errors currently, but the number is very low, only a few events per day. For us, this situation is acceptable. Of course, it is not ruled out that more errors may occur later, and we will keep monitoring.
Are you experiencing a large number of events? We used to have thousands of events per day.

Exactly the same here, cross project. All look like this:
TypeError instrumentFetch(utils/build/esm/instrument)

or
TypeError: Load failed

All originating from gtag scripts, more specific POST requests from the gtag script to links like this:

POST https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=xxxxxxxxxxx
POST https://region1.analytics.google.com/g/collect?v=xxxxxxxx

According to Sentry reports it happens cross browser:

Chrome Mobile 125.0.0 - 35%
Instagram 335.0.0 - 13%
Facebook 461.0.0 - 8%
Facebook 467.1.0 - 7%

Started since the beginning of June (first on our apps on June 5th)
It does not happen to all requests for the same user. Sometimes 5 calls are OK (tracking page views), then 2 fail, ...
At first I thought it had something to do with some kind of 'privacy' protection that randomly hits on new browser versions. But I thought this was only going to happen on new Chrome releases + it also happens on other browsers. Maybe it's something that's going on at Sentry.

We are experiencing multiple gtag/js failed to fetch errors, which began at the start of June without any prior changes to our codebase. Our first hypothesis is that this issue is linked to Chrome's third-party cookie restriction rolling out across 2024. This new policy might be affecting how Google Tag Manager operates, especially concerning the SameSite attribute for cookies. As you mention, the errors all originate from the gtag scripts.
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/14439269?hl=en

The errors I'm seeing aren't only affecting Chrome. There's what looks like a closely related Load failed on a gtag POST that affects Safari (multiple versions) - that kicked off around the same time as the issue described above.
Does Google have anywhere official to report gtag issues? I couldn't find an issues page similar to those that exist for many other projects (e.g. the Maps SDKs, or Analytics)

It appears that the issue resolved itself around June 21st for us. We did not make any changes on our end, suggesting that Google likely addressed the problem on their side. We have not received any new events on Sentry since then.

This morning, I suddenly received an e-mail from Sentry:

Hi there,
We're writing to notify you that we recently enabled additional inbound filters for your JavaScript projects. Now, error events from browser extensions, legacy browsers, and web crawlers will be automatically filtered out for the following projects:
xxx
xxx
This change should help reduce error noise for you and your team. If you prefer to see these errors, you can modify your inbound filters at any time by clicking the links above.

I can see that they enabled the following filters:

Filter out errors known to be caused by browser extensions
Filter out health check transactions
Filter out legacy browsers
Filter out known web crawlers

I'll keep you updated if events are still triggered from now on.

These options have been enabled in our Sentry project's Inbound Filters for a very long time, so I doubt they are related ?

Same issues running sentry-rails 5 in AWS. The error is still happening as of today. It could possibly be related to the upcoming July 1 cutoff to legacy google analytics. Theoretically it should not, but maybe google is busy fixing some last minute changes.
